# How to align taskbar icons to the left

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, alignment

Using Windows 10.
I have read that this is on by default but for some reason, it doesn't work for me. The problem is that when i open a new app (one that isn't pinned), its icon appears on the taskbar normally, but it gets shifted by one icon to the right like in the image below:[image: taskbar]

It isn't a major issue, but it bothers me... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Right click on the task bar and uncheck "Lock the Taskbar" .  Restart the computer and see if if is now at the left. If so, Lock it again

Comment: Reporting back in a few minutes! @John

Comment: Well boys, we did it, frustration is no more!

Comment: So then if I post my comment as an answer, would you accept it?

Comment: I posted an answer for you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the task bar and uncheck "Lock the Taskbar".

Restart the computer and see if if is now at the left.

If so, Lock it again to keep it that way

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who don't want to reboot, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and open *Task Manager*. In the *Process* tab, find *Windows Explorer* and restart it.

Comment: the shortcut to open task manager is Ctrl+Shift+Esc, not Ctrl+Alt+Del

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by @John , a simple fix is to  lock the taskbar and reboot. Feeling a bit silly to be honest...

Comment: Pls Accept John answer instead of posting this.